# Send SMS with custom sender id using amazon notification service

Tags: amazon-web-services, sms, amazon-sns

Iam using amazon notification service for sending SMS. i successfully got the message to my number. i have updated the sender id using aws console like this.

[image]

But i got SMS like this

```
from : VK-NOTICE
Body : test message
```

from id is diifrent. why? is it possible to change sender id ?

Comment: TRAI does not allow dynamic sender name so you can use any local [sms gatewayAPI services](https://www.springedge.com)  to setup your own sender id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to TRAI length of sender id in transactional sms should be 6 in India and yours is 5 (MANAF) that's why it is changing it to default. To use your sender id in transactional sms use id with character length of 6. Ex(AbdulM)

Note: It only works with transactional Sms.

Comment: I got this worked as per your suggestion , i had changed the length to 6 and it was working. And suddenly after some months , its not working , getting the default sender id string now. Any idea what could cause this ? Anyone else faced this ?

Comment: What if the country is UK ?

Comment: Have to send sms with two different sender Id, so used the senderID configuration in params , but still the default one in sms, even after keeping the default as empty.

Answer (score 3):

AWS Docs have the answer here:

> For Default sender ID, type a custom ID that contains up to 11 alphanumeric characters, including at least one letter and no spaces.
>   The sender ID is displayed as the message sender on the receiving
>   device. For example, you can use your business brand to make the
>   message source easier to recognize.
>
> Support for sender IDs varies by country. For example, messages
>   delivered to U.S. phone numbers will not display the sender ID. For
>   the countries that support sender IDs, see Supported Regions and
>   Countries.
>
> If you do not specify a sender ID, the message will display a long
>   code as the sender ID in supported countries. For countries that
>   require an alphabetic sender ID, the message displays NOTICE as the
>   sender ID.
>
> You can override the this setting when you send a message.

You should try https://www.twilio.com/

Comment: My country is said to support sender ID, but what i type in is ignored...

Answer (score 0):

As on 2 Nov 2018, Custom sender ID is not supported for India. See below link for current supported countries.

[AWS SNS Supported Countries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_supported-countries.html)